# Programmatic Symbolication of Crash Logs

Tags: xcode, crash, symbolicatecrash, symbolicate, dsym

I am attempting to symbolicate crash logs that I have automatically sent to a server. My app's crash logs and dSYM files are sent to the server upon my app crashing. The issue I am having is symbolicating them. I would like to do this programmatically so that the process can be automated. Thus I am trying to use the symbolicatecrash terminal command as a subprocess in a python script. But before I even try to implement that, I need to get symbolicatecrash working properly. entering the following command is unsuccessful;

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash -o /Users/aj/Documents/symbolicatedcrash.crash com.COMPANYNAME.TEST_APP.crash TEST_APP.app.dSYM

I use the -o option to write the output to a file. Entering this code does not return an error. The output file is created, the crash log is just not symbolicated.

From researching peoples' similar questions, I've found that downloading the .ipa file and unzipping it can help. I have done so and found that the symbolicatecrash command does indeed symbolicate if the .app file is on the server.

My issue is that I do not want to download the .ipa file. Downloading it every time there is a new crash (or at least a new build) would be inefficient for the server. I would just like to download the dSYM and crash file itself upon each app crash.

My question is ultimately then: Can I symbolicate a crash log by using just the dSYM file? If so, can it be done with the symbolicatecrash terminal command?

Thanks

Comment: Check this link - it may be helpful 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports?rq=1

Comment: Thanks! after further experimentation, I found that you indeed need the .ipa file/ or the archived app binaries to fully symbolicate the crash log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after further experimentation, I found that you indeed need the .ipa file or the archived app binaries to fully symbolicate the crash log.

you do not need to include those files in the terminal command though; The example I gave in the question works if you have the app binaries anywhere on your computer. The command will use spotlight to find the app binaries, and then return a fully symbolicated crash log.

note: it important that your binaries/crash log/dSYM files all come from the same build to have a fully symbolicated log.

Comment: Interesting. This seems to contradict what Crashlytics says in response to this Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163455/dsym-and-binary-required-to-symbolicate-or-just-dsym

Comment: @stonedauwg Hmm, interesting. although I've been away from this problem for awhile, I wonder if the dSYMs are the only component you need to symbolicate like that link mentions. Perhaps manually symbolication requires the other files to be present for security purposes, and crashlytics has found a way around that. Or now that a couple years have passed the process could also have been updated.